# PySide does not import QtGui

Tags: windows, pyside, qt5

I get the following error on trying to execute a simple hello world  QT app.

c:\Repos\gui>python ex1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex1.py", line 2, in 
    from PySide import QtGui
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

I saw that an earlier solution recommended adding qt bin folder to Path variable. I tried to add but I apparently have many folders in C:\Qt\5.1.0. I tried adding "C:\Qt\5.1.0\msvc2012\bin" to path but nothing changed. I also saw that Qt5Gui is present but no QtGui.

As Qt\5.1.0\ has many folders for msvs, I was wondering if i was missing something special for python.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, PySide does not support Qt5.
(http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:LanguageBindings::PySide)